# Simple submit form to go to a page

Tags: php, html, forms, input, hyperlink

I have some numbered pages:

```
1.php
2.php
3.php
etc.
```

I want to create a textbox that the user enter any number: `2` for example, and hit enter or `Go` button, and they will go to the page `2.php` depending on the number entered.

I know how to link to a specific page as in `form action="...."`, but I am not sure how to echo the user input and translate it as link (whether using html or php).

Ex:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="number" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Comment: Use a redirect to `$_POST['number' ] . ".php"`

Comment: Or use client-side JavaScript to change the `action` when the user enters something in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an action attribute to your form and a name attribute to your number input.  The file from your action attribute will "catch" the POST variables and do the logic needed to redirect your user.  Change your form tag to:

```
<form method="POST" action="redirect.php">
  <input type="number" value="" name="redirect" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Then create the `redirect.php` file that gets the POST variables and does the redirection:

```php
<?php

$redirectPage = (int) $_POST['redirect'];
$redirectUrl = "http://www.example.com/{$redirectPage}.php";
header("Location: $redirectUrl");
printf('<a href="%s">moved</a>.', $redirectUrl);
```

Beware that there's no input validation nor error handling included.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the best available option in your case would be the one using client-side javascript to dynamically change the form's **action** attribute base on the number entered in the input box.

A quick and dirty solution to fulfil such a task might look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function submitAction(formElement) {
   var // get the input box element
       el = document.getElementById('form-action-number'),
       // get a number specified by user in the input box
       num = parseInt(el.value), 
       // validate that it's really a number and is greater than zero
       // (you don't want someone to request -666.php right? :)
       // build a page url using the correct number
       page = !isNaN(num) && num > 0 ? num.toFixed(0).toString() + '.php' : undefined;

   if (page) { // the page url is valid
      // set form's action attribute to an url specified by page variable
      formElement.setAttribute('action', page);
      // returning true will allow the form to be submitted
      return true; 
   }

   // you might think of a better way to notify user that the input number is invalid :)
   console.error('INVALID NUMBER SPECIFIED!');
   // returning false will prevent form submission
   return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- When user clicks Go, the return value of submitAction function will be used to decide if the form should be submitted or not -->
  <form method="POST" onsubmit="return submitAction(this)">
    <input id="form-action-number" type="number" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With PHP you can do something like this:

```
<?php
// Check if the POST value has been set
if(isset($_POST['my_number'])) {
    // Redirect to the corresponding page
    header('Location: ' . $_POST['my_number'] . '.php');
}
?>

<form method="POST">
    <input name="my_number" type="number" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Comment: This code example is prone to location header injection and does not serve well as an example (not helpful).

Answer (score 0):

This is like DaMeGeX's answer but uses javascript to go to the new page.

```
<?php
// Check if the POST value has been set
if(isset($_POST['my_number'])) {
    // Redirect to the corresponding page
    echo "<script> window.location.href = '".$_POST['number'].".php' </script>";
}
?>

<form method="POST">
    <input name="my_number" type="number" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Comment: It's unnecessary to use JavaScript to do this when PHP is already being used, and has the capability to redirect.

Comment: I agree the PHP header function is more direct, but when I made this post there was a comment saying that the header function was not working for him, so I put this out as an easy alternative. But yes I agree the built in PHP function would be my first go to as well.

Comment: If the Location response header doesn't work what is the rationale to jump on a script tag? The accepted answer **shows** that the header function **is** working. And even if not, why should the fix be a script tag? Especially as I as another user give you this comment: "Javascript window.location.href is not working for me". If sending the location response header does not work (or the browser does not automatically redirect), provide human-readable information with the response  what the redirect address is (e.g. a link). Compare with the HTTP standard.